# Сохранить картику с Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно из `Bitmap` создать картинку формата `*.png` или `*.jpg`
Помогите!

Comment: [Метод Image.Save (String, ImageFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202797/save-bitmap-as-jpg-to-folder-in-pictures-in-windows-8-app-c-sharp

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Windows Form C#

Comment: Помог вариант Grundy!

Comment: @VladD, а там есть разница в битмапах?

Comment: @Grundy: Разумеется. У WPF [свои битмапы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VladD, Ну не, BitmapSource это ж не Bitmap :-D

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, мало ли как ТС называет свой объект. Я бы не закладывался на точное название.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помог [метод Image.Save (String, ImageFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Bitmap PictureImg = new Bitmap(2560, 1920);

PictureImg.Save("img.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```